# what is the best way for web adressing

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

I want to ask about friendly URLs in web addressing.

I am showing users product informations on my web application. I don't want to show URLs like *xxx.aspx?Id=yyy*; I want to show URLs like *http://example.net/xxx/yyy* to get values for yyy from database, or another example *https://eksisozluk.com/entry/27279462*.

My database table has columns id, name, info, img, etc.

Right now the website has URLs like **xxx.net/product.aspx?=productid**, but I wish them to be like **xxx.net/product/product-name-here**.

Comment: Hi ATA, and welcome to Stack Overflow. The URLs you refer to are called *friendly URLs*, and you may find some useful answers if you search for [friendly-url](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/friendly-url) or [url-rewrite-module](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/url-rewrite-module) on this site.

Comment: I have restructured your question a little to make the english a bit more standard, and the example URLs a bit more comparable. Further editing is encouraged, as you clarify your question in response to other users' comments for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you want is `URL Rewriting` and `Routing` which you can get it from official [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.aspx) for `ASP.Net` from `Microsoft`.

In this documentation you can set your website routing schema as you wish (Like what you mentioned in your post).

If you develop an ASP.Net webform application, Just see this [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd329551.aspx).

Hope this help you bro.